# Fixed leak under sink - is there damage under the cabinet floor?

Tags: kitchens, leak, sink, damage

I apologize in advance if this has already been answered, I searched but could not find anything specific to my inquiry.

I found a leak underneath my kitchen sink due to water leaking out from the cabinet onto the floor while doing dishes. Upon opening the cabinet I found the cabinet floor pooled with water. I have since fixed the leak, dried and aired out the area, and everything seems to be fine - my question is, there are holes on the cabinet floor for the hot and cold water supply lines, as well as the drain pipe. I'm worried water got into these holes during the leak - is there anything I need to do or be worried about regarding water damage in the dead space behind the toe kick underneath the cabinet floor? Since it was only one occurrence, is it safe to assume that it will evaporate and no long term damage will be an issue? If the damage is only superficial, I don't feel that would be an issue since it is in the dead space/non-visible area underneath the cabinet floor. But I just wanted to make sure I wasn't ignoring any potential subfloor issue or anything like that. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Joey

[image: underneath sink]

[image: under cabinet floor]

Comment: Permanently seal those openings with silicone.

Comment: Thank you both - I will get those holes sealed to prevent this from happening again in the future. I attached a picture of what I saw after removing the vent cover attached to the toekick. I apologize for the crumbs, I haven't yet gotten everything cleaned up. But from what I could see it seemed pretty dry under there - there are some water drop spots on the back board as seen in the picture but I'm guessing they're small enough that they will evaporate and not be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you found the leak pretty quickly and that it hasn't been leaking for months/years, it's likely that the floor under the cabinet will be just fine.

Based on the picture it doesn't look like it's particularly bad under there, but it is hard to tell. Maybe another picture with a flashlight lighting up the area behind the toe kick will help you see it better to determine if there's any real significant structural water damage.